# Identify the class of object, Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new in a Scala and need help to read some piece of the code. I'm looking now for the next code: [ALS.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala) from [Apache Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark) and try to understand, how it works and which classes/objects are involved in this source code.
Currently I have difficulty with the [line 166](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L166) in the code, because I can not understand the nature of the `SchemaUtils` object.

I copied already the source code to my local repository and got an recognition error for `SchemaUtils` object. In my `pom.xml` I defined the Spark version `1.6.1`, but I suppose this object is not anymore available in this version (probably older one). Consequently is not recognized by Scala. The error message is:

```
not found: value SchemaUtils
```

How I can fix this bug?

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>als</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!---->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- for fatjar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-scala-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.15.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute></execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post your `pom.xml`

Comment: @Tzach Zohar, Thank you for your respond. I do hope, I did it already. If you can help me, I post my pom.xml for details.

Comment: You can't use `SchemaUtils` in your code since it's private to `org.apache.spark`: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/SchemaUtils.scala#L26

Comment: And how I can replace it? Is it some solution to runniing the initial code of ALS.scala on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html)

> For the Scala API, Spark 1.6.1 uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.10.x).

You can't use 2.11 with Spark (yet), so change your `<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>` and all related dependencies with the Scala version encoded to read `_2.10` and try that.

Comment: thank you very much. Sorry, I'm really total newcomer in scala

Comment: 1. Spark can be built for 2.11. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211

Comment: 2. It's not about scala complexity. It's about spark code legacy that requires crossBuild production libraries (2.11 for services and 2.10 for spark job). Problems arrive when serialization is needed, because of collections are incompatible

Comment: @Zernike, yes, this is true, the problem with SchemaUtils is not away... I'm going to understand the answer of Tzach Zohar and try to find some solution...